# mysql search, returning the column names where the search was successful

Tags: mysql, search

I have a very simple search query that looks like this

```
select * from products_stock where (
    title like '%$searchterm%' or 
    short_desc like '%$searchterm%' or 
    long_desc like '%searchterm%'
)
```

When I get a hit from the column long_desc, I want to program in some special behaviour in PHP. Is there any way to get the mysql results to highlight which column the search was successful in?

Comment: you mean 3 titles title short_desc long_desc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use derived fields. Looks ugly, but works:

```
SELECT *, (title LIKE '%$searchterm%') AS found_in_title,
     (short_desc LIKE '%$searchterm%') AS found_in_short_desc
     etc...
```

the LIKE will return a boolean true/false as a field in your result set, and the AS alias will tell you which field the match occured in.

Note that you'd probably be much better off using a fulltext index for these sorts of things. `LIKE '%...%'` matches cannot use indexes, and performance will be utterly abysmal on "large" tables.

Comment: Performance _is_ utterly abysmal, you are right there. The actual production query is more complex, and I think re-writing to use fulltext searching is sensible, but what you've given me will do in the meantime.